# Is it possible for CPU to do context-switch after initiating GPU source code(cuda kernel) that is not finished?

Tags: cuda, gpu, cpu, context-switch

Basically, in CPU and GPU communication, if a process running over a CPU initiates a cuda kernel, process still can issues its code if it is not dependent on the result of cuda kernel.

But, is it possible for a process running over CPU to do context-switch even after initiating a cuda kernel that is not finished?

If it is possible, what happens internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CPU threads can context-switch at any time, including during a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` call waiting for results from a (asynchronous) kernel launch.

You can further facilitate context-switching during synchronization by calling [`cudaSetDeviceFlags()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g69e73c7dda3fc05306ae7c811a690fac) with the `cudaDeviceScheduleYield` or `cudaDeviceScheduleBlockingSync` flags, which will yield the processor quicker than the `cudaDeviceScheduleSpin` or `cudaDeviceScheduleAuto` settings.